# проблема с валидацией кириллицы в ActiveRecord yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord, кириллица

Есть форма, когда `entype` стоит `multipart/form-data`, то текст введенный в поле ввода, передается как "Ð¹ÑÑÐ¹ÑÑ". Если же enctype не указан, то все в порядке

Comment: Кодировку файлов с кодом проверяли?

Answer (score 1):

Уже разобрался.  кодировка стоит везде utf-8, проблема не в этом. а в том что при `entype=multipart/form-data` текст с кодировкой utf перекодирует в другой. Так происходит потому что в ini файле включен  `mbstring.encoding_translation`. Поставив его значение в off все начинает работать как следует